# Correct way to create an array with multiple children

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object with looks like recursive until level 3.

```
const mainArr = [{
    children: [{
        children: [{
            children: [{
                children: [{}],
                level: 3
            }],
            level: 2
        }],
        level: 1
    }],
    level: 0
}]
```

I want to create an array with Level 2 object that have child items

Here is my way to achieve what i want but it looks like a bad way.

```
reasons = [
  ...[...data.map((level0) => level0.children)]
    .flat()
    .map((level1) => level1.children)
    .flat(),
].filter((level2) => level2.children.length);
```

I want to improve code block that i give in above

(edited)
Output

```json
[
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Reason",
                "level": 3
            }
        ],
        "level": 2
    },
    {
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Reason2",
                "level": 3
            }
        ],
        "level": 2
    }
]
```

Comment: can you provide the desired output

Comment: output added @HoangSon